# Use the ConvNext classifier layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

Inside the source code of the Convnext:

```py
self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    norm_layer(lastconv_output_channels), nn.Flatten(1), nn.Linear(lastconv_output_channels, num_classes)
)
```

When I call the pretrained model and I want to change in the classifier layer `norm_layer` is not defined and I don't know how to use it from the source code

```py
model = torchvision.models.convnext_base(prtrained=True, stochastic_depth_prob=0.1,
                                         layer_scale=1e-4)

model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
   ** norm_layer**(1024), nn.Flatten(1), nn.Linear(1024, 7)
)
```

Please anyone can help to write it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `norm_layer` is given in line 113 [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7e9e7844e7652bf7b90eef2e9b9397bd20c00e4c/torchvision/models/convnext.py#L113C12-L113C12), as

```
norm_layer = partial(LayerNorm2d, eps=1e-6)
```

where everything is well-defined if you import `from torchvision.models.convnext import LayerNorm2d` and `from functools import partial`.

Using this (and fixing the spelling of `pretrained`), your code should work. :)